# SharpRepository is not disposing of repositories in testing?

Tags: c#, testing, sharp-repository

I'm trying to write an integration test for my application that utilizes entity framework and sharprepository. I'm writing some tests at the moment and I've noticed that data that I add to the repository in the tests is not being removed when I call Dispose() during TestCleanup. My code is as follows:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        var config = new EntityFrameworkRepositoryConfiguration(null);
        _factory = new BasicRepositoryFactory(config);
        _channelRepository = _factory.CreateRepository<Channel>();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        _channelRepository.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCreateRepositoryAndExecuteGetAllWithoutExceptions()
    {
        _channelRepository.GetAll();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCreateRepositoryAndInsertIntoItWithoutExceptions()
    {
        var repo = _factory.CreateRepository<Channel>();
        // NB: We can't mock this. Has to be real stuff.
        var channel = new Channel() { Id = 1 };

        _channelRepository.Add(channel);

        Assert.AreSame(channel, _channelRepository.Get(1));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCreateRepositoryAndFindSingleElementBasedOnPredicate()
    {
        var channels = new[]
        {
            new Channel(),
            new Channel(),
            new Channel()
        };

        _channelRepository.Add(channels);

        var firstOfPredicate = _channelRepository.Find(x => x.Id > 3);
        Assert.IsTrue(_channelRepository.Count() == channels.Length,
            "Seeded array has {0} elements, but the repository has {1}.",
            channels.Length,
            _channelRepository.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(channels[2].Id, firstOfPredicate.Id);
    }
```

The main purpose of these tests is not to test the SharpRepository implementation of EntityFramework, but rather to make sure that I've configured Entity Framework correctly. `EntityFrameworkRepositoryConfiguration` simply contains a connection string, which is passed to `BasicRepositoryFactory` - which literally just calls `return RepositoryFactory.GetInstance<T>();`.

My issue is is that `ShouldCreateRepositoryAndFindSingleElementBasedOnPredicate` fails because the element added in `ShouldCreateRepositoryAndInsertIntoItWithoutExceptions` is still in the repository - even though the repository should have been disposed in `Cleanup`.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: When you say that the elements that got added in the first test are still in the repository, what exactly do you mean?  What is the EF repository pointing to?  I might be confused, but when you do the add, the data will be added to the database that the connection string points to so it will be there unless you make some delete calls to remove it.  I might be missing something though or misunderstood the issue.

Comment: I was stupid. I thought Repository worked like the EF repository (a la, you don't commit changes unless they are committed); it doesn't, I discovered Batches last night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stupid - I automatically assumed that IRepository would work like the Entity Framework repository in that all actions are interally queued until you call SaveChanges; nope. What actually happens is that all changes are committed immediately when you use any CRUD operation on IRepository.

I discovered Batches last night, which are basically delayed queue actions. I should use those for tests, rather than IRepository.